# (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

Tags: macos, mac, nginx, docker

I am bit of a noob here and I'm looking for some help with something I have got stuck with. I did thoroughly check Google and here for people who had experienced the same problem, but adding or removing lines from etc/hosts has not helped anything sadly. I have been scratching my head over this for a couple days now.

I am in the process of following this blog - http://habd.as/simple-websites-jekyll-docker/#connect-to-jekyll-site

I have built the container and its running, I can check this with `docker ps`

How ever, when I run `curl localhost` - I get the following error

**curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused**

I am on my MacBook running El Captain - 10.11.1

Many thanks for any help,
Kirito

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't have any web server running on that port, sometimes web servers utilities like MAMP, set port to 8080, test that one.